# Platform.io - how to compile just library files, which are used in project

Tags: platformio

I'm using library ESP8266 audio, which contains lot of files. I'm using just a few of them, but when I want to build my project, platformio tryes to complie ewerything. It's quite issue, because unused filles has dependecies, which are not included in my project (eg. SD card library, file system library...). I can build my code with arduino IDE without any issues, but I'm not able to do the same thing in platformio. I tried to tweak src_filter flag, but it has no effect at all. I'm stucked on this for more than day and I wasn't able to find any relevant informations :/
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I solved it myself! :D I have set 'lib_ldf_mode' to 'deep' on platformio.ini. It's now acts exactly as I need. It starts in 'src/' folder and then recursively compiles imports and imports of imports and so on.